# Using an STL Iterator without initialising it

Tags: c++, stl, scope, iterator

I would like to do something like this:

```
container::iterator it = NULL;

switch ( eSomeEnum )
{
case Container1:
it = vecContainer1.begin();
break;

case Container2:
it = vecContainer2.begin();
break;
...


}

for( ; it != itEnd ; ++it )
{ 
..
}
```

But I can't create and initialise an iterator to NULL. Is there some way I can do this? Ideally I would just create and assign the iterator in the switch, but then it would go out of scope immediately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just needn't initialize it at all, because iterators are DefaultConstructible.

Answer (score 6):

All you should need to do is change

```
container::iterator it = NULL;
```

to

```
container::iterator it;
```

and I think your code will work as intended.

Comment: The OP stated that he can't do it, g++ and clang++ do not accept a null comparison or a null initialization. So AFAIK this is a meaningless answer, you shouldn't post things you "think" about as when it turns out wrong it harms the community in general.

Comment: This answer is essentially the same as the one that was accepted. How is it wrong? I'm happy to correct mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

You actually need a range, not just begin iterator. Note, you can't compare iterators from different containers, so you better off selecting the range, not the iterator. You can use [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/range/index.html) to achieve it:

```
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

boost::iterator_range< container::iterator > r;
switch( e )
{
    case Container1:
        r = boost::make_iterator_range( vecContainer1 );
    break;

    case Container2:
        r = boost::make_iterator_range( vecContainer2 );
    break;

    ...
}

BOOST_FOREACH( container::value_type value, r )
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the loop tests for end, you should construct it to value what `itEnd` values.